# Will Google OAuth issue a new refresh token automatically?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

There is one use case using Google OAuth2 where it's not clear from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) what will happen.

Let's assume that I have a user, who granted my app offline access. I receive a refresh token and use it for some time. Then the user becomes inactive and I don't use refresh token for more than 6 months. Then the user comes back again.

According to documentation my refresh token will be expired. I assume I can get a new one if I direct a user to a consent screen again using approval_prompt parameter.
The question is whether I have to do it. Will Google OAuth  return a new refresh token the next time a user signs in, even if I don't use approval_prompt?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is send the user through the authentication process again and you will get a new refresh token for the user. You shouldn't have to do anything special or even explicitly set `approval_prompt` to anything.